# Add marker on Google map on button left click. Trying to modify one example

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Here is example https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/context_menu.html

Copy the code here

```
map.setContextMenu({
  control: "map",
  options: [{
    title: "Add marker",
    name: "add_marker",
      action: function(e) {
      this.addMarker({
      lat: e.latLng.lat(),
      lng: e.latLng.lng()
      });
    }
  }]
});
```

On right click see `Add marker`. Left click on marker and see marker on the map.

But want to add marker on left click

Tried

```
map = new GMaps({
  click: function(event) {

  //alert("click");
  var lat=event.latLng.lat();
  var lng=event.latLng.lng();
  alert ( lat+ ", "+ lng );

   this.addMarker({
   lat: event.latLng.lat(),
   lng: event.latLng.lng(),
   });

  }
});
```

When left click works `alert ( lat+ ", "+ lng );`, but no marker added. What need to correct?

**Solution** appears very simple

```
map = new GMaps({
  click: function(event) {

  //alert("click");
  var lat=event.latLng.lat();
  var lng=event.latLng.lng();
  alert ( lat+ ", "+ lng );

   map.addMarker({
   lat: lat,
   lng: lng,
   });

  }
});
```

Comment: I guess you have to handle MouseClick, Marker yourself. I'll post some example

Comment: Found solution based on this https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html example. Now need to understand how to remove previous marker if click another place....

Comment: See removeMarkers from here http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-hideInfoWindows

Comment: Thanks. I actually don't know about the library gmaps and glad I found it through you. I was doin it all hardcore coding. This libray would make my life easier in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//This is just  a snippet. Please read InfoWindow and Marker from Google Map API Library

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '' //content is your HTML/div element  with a menu this is where your menu context is located
});


 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: 'your title',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(yourlat, yourlng),
    map: map //your map
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    infowindow.setContent(html); 
    infowindow.open(map, marker); 
});
```